# How can allow_nil let an empty string pass the validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am reading Michael Hartl's *Ruby On Rails Tutorial (3rd)*. In chapter 9, there's an example showing us how to update the user info. I got confused by the allow_nil attached here. I simplified the code as below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
end

myuser=User.new(name: "Foo_bar",email: "test@example.com", password: "123456", password_confirmation: "123456")
myuser.save
myuser=User.find(myuser.id)
myuser.update_attributes(name: "Bar_Foo",email: "test@example.com", password: "", password_confirmation: "")  # It will succeed! But WHY?
```

I understand the `allow_nil: true` skips the validation when the value being validated is nil. Nevertheless obviously, `password: ""` is not a nil value. How can `allow_nil: true` allows an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in irb:

```
  user = User.new
  user.password = '123'
  user.password_confirmation = '123' 
  user.password_digest.nil?  => false 

  user = User.new
  user.password = ''
  user.password_confirmation = '' 
  user.password_digest.nil?  => true
```

Comment: That is not correct, Empty string is not nil, and if you tried any value other than empty string it will return nil also.

Comment: `puts` always returns nil, it does not mean that `a` is nil. Test it with `a.nil?`

Comment: the `puts` method returns nil

Comment: Much better now, still however validation is on `password`, not `password_digest`

Comment: `has_secure_password` always check the validation with `password_digest` field

Comment: Yes, but validation in the question does not. :)

Comment: I agree with @BroiSatse. I didn't find any proof that  the `allow_nil: true` is applied to `password_digest`.

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is due to `has_secure_password` magic. In short, it check whether given password is blank or not and does not assign anything to `@password` if it is. Hence:

```
user = User.new
user.password = '' # This is not an assignment, but invocation of `password=` method.
user.password #=> nil
```

You can see the source code behind `password=` method here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/869a90512f36b04914d73cbf58317d953caea7c5/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L122

Also note, that `has_secure_password` already defines default password validation, so if you want to create your own, you need to call it with `has_secure_password validation: false`

Comment: `user.password.nil?  #=>false` how it will be nil

Comment: This will only occur if you have `has_secure_password` implemented in your model.

Comment: If we call it with `has_secure_password validation: false` . Then the question remains. If the `allow_nil: true` is removed , validate will fail.  So it means `allow_nil: true` is still applied to `password_digest` ?

Comment: Is there a way around this other than writing password=(password) from scratch? It'd be nice to implement a minimum password length